# How to print data of Map as a table?

Tags: haskell

I have a `Map (Int, Int) a` where `a` can be any type. Based on the Tuple2 stored in the array as key I wanna create a String table which stores the values of the map.

Because the maximal values of the Tuple2 are known and can be large, my first thought was to create a mutable 2D-Array with a default value. While iterating over the entries of the Map, this array could be filled and then printed out. A pseudo-code example with a Map of Ints:

```
map = Map (Int, Int) Int
table = Array.ofDim (maxY, maxX) withDefaultValue 0
for ((x,y), int) <- map do
  table[y][x] = int
end
rows = table.rows map toString
str = rows map (toString ++ lineEnd)
print str
```

The only problem is: I don't know how to do this in Haskell. Furthermore I don't know if this is the preferred way one goes in Haskell.

I didn't find good examples how to use 2D-Arrays in Haskell, thus can someone give me one? If there is a better way to do this, maybe with a built-in data type such as Table, Matrix, 2DStringBuilder etc., can someone show me an example how to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table = Array.ofDim (maxY, maxX) withDefaultValue 0
```

That can be done with

```
table :: Array (Int,Int) Int
table = array ((0,0),(maxX,maxY))
               [((i,j),Map.findWithDefault 0 (i,j) map) | i <- [0 .. maxX], j <- [0 .. maxY]]
```

Then for tabular output of any two-dimensional array,

```
rows :: Array (Int,Int) a -> [[a]]
rows arr = [[arr ! (r,c) | c <- [clow .. chigh]] | r <- [rlow .. rhigh]]
  where
    ((rlow,clow),(rhigh,chigh)) = bounds arr

rowStrings :: Show a => Array (Int,Int) a -> [String]
rowStrings arr = [unwords (map show row) | row <- rows arr]

tableString :: Show a => Array (Int,Int) a -> String
tableString arr = unlines (rowStrings arr)

prettyPrint :: Show a => Array (Int,Int) a -> IO ()
prettyPrint arr = putStr (tableString arr)
```

You can also define some the functions point-free,

```
prettyPrint = putStr . tableString

tableString = unlines . rowStrings

rowStrings = map (unwords . map show) . rows
```

`rows` and `table` are not comfortably defined point-free, though, so I stop here.

Comment: This works equally well (albeit maybe slower) by not constructing the array and doing lookups in the map instead of indexing into the array.